# Issue with date field in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have date value retrived in dataset column as "9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM"
Now I am writing the following code for displaying it in textbox

```
var date = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ExpiryDate"].ToString();
txtExpiryDate.Text = date.ToString();
```

It is being displayed in the textbox as "91/42/0161"
I want that it should display date in mm/dd/yyyy format that is 09/14/2016 or 9/14/2016.
I am not able to tackle this issue... Please help !!!

Comment: is the `date` variable stores correct value?

Comment: let me check ....

Comment: I'm assuming that `"ExpiryDate"` has incorrect data. BTW you did 2 `.ToString()`

Comment: yes it is being entered in ""09/14/2016"" format.

Comment: Does your `txtExpiryDate` have any mask applied ?

Comment: What format is `91/42/0161`? What is the 1 at the end?

Comment: Taking only a part of date value "9/14/2016 1", the displayed value can be created if we shift the position of / by one place on the right side. It will become 91/42/0161 (the bad value displayed in the `Textbox`). Is there something on the client side script that is altering the value on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's actually already a `DateTime` you don't need to convert it to string and then back to `DateTime`. [`DataRowExtensions.Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298012(v=vs.110).aspx) comes in handy here:

```
DateTime date = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("ExpiryDate");
```

The method also supports nullable types. So if that column could be null:

```
DateTime? dateOrNull = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime?>("ExpiryDate");
if(dateOrNull.HasValue) Console.Write(dateOrNull.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

To get your desired format you can use:

```
string result = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it

```
var date = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ExpiryDate"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
txtExpiryDate.Text = date;
```

Comment: In the given code, the variable `date` will be string. then why are you converted it again using `.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
txtExpiryDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ExpiryDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Or

```
 txtExpiryDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ExpiryDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are numerous way to do this, in your case you are assigning string without proper format. replace your code with mine and you will see it working.

```
txtExpiryDate.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ExpiryDate"]));
```

Comment: what will happen if the value is null?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, any of the answers given here should work for you. This is something else that is causing the issue to you.

You should debug the value in the c# code and even at the client side script for this problem.

As I have commented above:

> Taking only a part of date value "9/14/2016 1", the displayed value can be created if we shift the position of / by one place on the right side. It will become 91/42/0161 (the bad value displayed in the Textbox). Is there something on the client side script that is altering the value on the page.

You should debug to get your work done.